# Getting JQuery-lib from Google with fallback to local server

Tags: jquery

I've found a little script here in stackoverflow which allows me to load the JQuery lib from Google with a fallback to the local server. So I implement this in my site.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write(&apos;<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">\x3C/script>&apos;)</script>
```

But firebug show me a syntax error after implementation:

```
syntax error
 window.jQuery || document.write(&apos;...uery-1.6.4.min.js">\x3C/script>&apos;)
```

Someone knows a workaround or a fix?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is the correct escaping for it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js" /></script>    
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js\"\>\</script\>')</script>
```

[**Working Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LpYF/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

    <strike>window.jQuery || document.write('');</strike>

No need for the entity shenanigans.

EDIT: interesting. It is dumping it out inside the script block, and then the javascript parser is falling over. Try this instead (I deliberately botched the CDN url so it would force the download of the local copy):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || function(){ var script=document.createElement('script');script.src='js/jquery.js'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); }();</script>
```

Comment: after this one firebug tells me "unterminated string literal
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">"

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is working for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
</script>
```